# Active Directory and Subdomains

Tags: active-directory

I want to configure 2 subdomains for 2 different locations within my domain forest. My question is how can I configure it so that users will be at the top forest level, and shared between both subdomains, but site specific assets such as servers and workstations are stored within each subdomain. Furthermore, each subdomain tree assets can DNS and get the corresponding assets of the entire forest?

Comment: um,  follow standard forest child domain infrastructure....

Comment: Why child domains? Why not use Organizational Units instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with sub-domains in a forest, create new domains as needed (each domain will require a couple of domain controllers) but  while this should work and the trust model in AD forests should mean that communication works ok, creating multiple domains is often a bad idea; when we moved to AD about 16 years ago we thought we were being clever collapsing 5 windows NT domains into 2 AD domains in 1 forest. With the benefit of hindsight I really wish we'd gone for just one domain.

You can do all this in multiple OUs within one domain which might be better, it will almost certainly be easier to manage anyway. You can separate users and resources into separate OUs and depending on why you want separation you can do one or several of the following:

1. If you're worried about multiple sites, you can create several sites in one domain, allowing devices and/or user auth to 'prefer' a DC in the same site rather than cross WAN links when it's not necessary.
2. If you need to maintain 'political' separation between different company departments, you can do this with splitting users and devices into  OUs. Y department and delegating admin rights (or whatever subset of rights you wish) to departmental admins who only have rights over 'their' OUs.